# postgresql update value based on date column

Tags: postgresql

I have two tables namely `task` and `taskstatus`.
In `task` table i have master data i.e., if task is created then status will be `new`
if task is assigned to a user then status will be `assigned`...
in the table `taskstatus` i want to insert in column called `assignedtask` as 1 based on current date.
if a new task is created for that same user then `assignedtask` column should get incremented by 1 based on current date.
if a task is created for next day then a new row should get inserted and above same steps should get repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a `task` is created, create a `taskstatus` entry for that `task`.

And when that `task` is `assigned` to any `user`,

```
Update taskstatus set assignedtask = (
  CASE WHEN date = NOW()::date THEN
    (assignedtask + 1)
  ELSE
    1
)
WHERE userid = your_user_id and taskid = your_task_id
```